# Showing and hiding menu items in django based on a non-permissions criteria?

Tags: python, django

I have a field on a `Company` called `leave_approvers` which is a `ManyToManyField` to `Users`.

The `leave_approvers` can approve leave of other users in the company they are a leave approver for. They also receive an email when leave is requested.

I would now like to show or hide the `Approve Leave` tab in the main layout based on whether the user is a `leave_approver`.

1. Is the decision to have a `leave_approver` field flawed as I should be using the built in authorisation or something like [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian). Note that I am sending an email to the `leave_approvers` and that would mean
2. Can I just make a query in the `base.html` to check if a user is a `leave_approver`. How can this be done and surely there is a performance hit?

Comment: Hi! How did you solve your problem? I'm facing similar, to display menu items set based on groups user in.

Comment: @МихаилПавлов Just answered the question, I hope it gives you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consideration making use of django permissions (which are added to the context via a context processor automatically) is the best route in my opinion. 
Using something like this in the template:

```
{% if perms.foo.can_vote %}
```

However, in my case I cut corners and make a query for all the leave approvers in the base template which is much slower than the prebuilt `perms` in the context.

```
{% if user in user.company.leave_approvers.all %}
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'leave:pending' %}">Pending Leave Approval</a></li>
{% endif %}
```